# unexpected end of json input cypress into post intercept

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

I tried intercept a POST request in my cypress test , but when i put a "json" as a fixture, cypress give the error "Unexpected end of json input", how can i pass the variable as a json data ?

**JSON (percentage.json):**

```
[
  {
    "totalPoints": 1,
    "corretas": 1,
    "totalIncorretas": [],
    "percentage": 25
  },
  {
    "totalPoints": 1,
    "corretas": 1,
    "totalIncorretas": [],
    "percentage": 100
  }
]
```

**Test:**

```
it('displays game over screen when user cannot make at least 63%', () => {
    var case1 = []
    cy.fixture('percentage.json').then((testData) => {
      case1 = testData[0]
      cy.log(case1)
    })
    cy.visit('http://localhost:5173/game_finished')
    cy.intercept("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/visitantes/sumuserpoints", {
      fixture: `${case1}`
    })
  })
```

the log of "case1" variable after the assignment results in a object with 4 keys (like the json), but gives the error mencioned before

Comment: Try setting `case1` to undefined or an empty object (`{}`) instead of an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few corrections you could make

#### Fixture option is a name

The intercept isn't correct, when you pass a `fixture` option it should be the name of the fixture file not the content

See [With a fixture](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#With-a-fixture)

> ```js
> // requests to '/users.json' will be fulfilled  
> // with the contents of the "users.json" fixture  
> cy.intercept('/users.json', { fixture: 'users.json' })
> ```

#### Using a static response

Technically you could use the value in variable `case1` as the body for a stubbed intercept,

See [With a StaticResponse object](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#With-a-StaticResponse-object)

```js
cy.intercept("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/visitantes/sumuserpoints", case1)
```

#### Avoiding the asynchronous trap

But in your code `case1` will still be empty because the fixture is read asynchronously. So the intercept will be set before `case1` receives a value.

Wrap it inside a `.then()` to handle the asynchronous problem.

```js
cy.then(() => {
  cy.intercept("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/visitantes/sumuserpoints", case1)
})
```